# Error calculating coefficient of variation (or any function with binary operators) with summarise() & across() of dplyr

Tags: r, function, character, numeric

I'm trying to calculate the mean, sd and coefficient of variation (cv) by tidyverse functions. No problem with mean or sd but with cv -as 100*(sd/mean)- it reports the following error:

```
Error in `dplyr::summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `..3 = across(where(is.numeric), (sd/mean) * 100, na.rm =
  TRUE, .names = "{col}_cv")`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: group = 1.
Caused by error in `sd / mean`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Take the following df as example (is not the real one, but the problem is the same):

```
df <- data.frame(group = as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)),
                 v1 = as.numeric(c(5,7,8,6,22,24,26,24)),
                 v2 = as.numeric(c(5,7,8,6,22,24,26,24)))
```

If I calculate the mean and sd there's no problem (except that I got two extra columns called v1_mean_sd and v2_mean_sd that are empty, but that's not my main problem):

```
df2 <-  df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% dplyr::summarise(
    across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "{col}_mean"),
    across(where(is.numeric), sd, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "{col}_sd"))
```

Then adding the calculation of cv to the code I got the mentioned error:

```
df2 <-  df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% dplyr::summarise(
    across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "{col}_mean"),
    across(where(is.numeric), sd, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "{col}_sd"),
    across(where(is.numeric), (sd/mean)*100, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "{col}_cv")) # Here the cv
```

I would expect to have the result for the cv as I had for the mean or the sd.
Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With compound functions, instead of using the argument, create a lambda expression.  Although, it is now recommended in tidyverse to use lambda even if we are passing a single function

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% dplyr::summarise(
    across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "{col}_mean"),
    across(where(is.numeric), sd, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "{col}_sd"),
    across(where(is.numeric), ~
    (sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)/mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))*100,  .names = "{col}_cv"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 15
  group v1_mean v2_mean v1_sd v2_sd v1_mean_sd v2_mean_sd v1_cv v2_cv v1_mean_cv v2_mean_cv v1_sd_cv v2_sd_cv v1_mean_sd_cv v2_mean_s…¹
  <fct>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>
1 1         6.5     6.5  1.29  1.29         NA         NA 19.9  19.9          NA         NA       NA       NA            NA          NA
2 2        24      24    1.63  1.63         NA         NA  6.80  6.80         NA         NA       NA       NA            NA          NA
# … with abbreviated variable name ¹​v2_mean_sd_cv
```

NOTE: There are some additional columns created because in each `across` with the numeric columns selected (`where(is.numeric)`), it selects all those columns that were already present in the initial data along with the new columns created in the `across` steps.  This could be avoided if we modify the `where(is.numeric)` in the second and third `across` to the specific column names or do this in a single `across`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(across(where(is.numeric), 
   list(mean = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
   sd = ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE), 
  cv = ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)/mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE) * 100)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
  group v1_mean v1_sd v1_cv v2_mean v2_sd v2_cv
  <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1         6.5  1.29 19.9      6.5  1.29 19.9 
2 2        24    1.63  6.80    24    1.63  6.80
```

Comment: @Bleras the reason is that you are using `where(is.numeric)`, thus it is looping over even the previously created output.  I thought your logic was to apply the subsequent `across` on all the columns including the ones that are previously created

Comment: Completely useful. I delete my previous comment just to remove repeated info. You will see my vote-up when I reach the 15 points required to vote. Thank you.